# How yii2 handles multiple databases in console?

Tags: database, yii2, console

I have a Yii2 backend app with the following database schema (hundred of databases).

```
  return [
      'components' => [
          'db1' => [
              'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
              'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb1',
              'username' => 'my_username1',
              'password' => 'my_password1',
          ],
          'db2' => [
              'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
              'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb2',
              'username' => 'my_username2',
              'password' => 'my_password2',
          ],
          ....

      ],
  ];
```

The app is used by multiple companies.
Every time a user of a company logs in I save the company identifier in a session variable to be able to access the specific database of each company through getDb().
My problem is that I can't run console commands because I don't have access to the session.
Any idea to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since it is a console command I would try environment variables or passing the identifier explicitly as parameter to the command. I think it would be helpful to have some more information what the process flow is that would trigger the console command. If it should be triggered via a request I would think about some kind of queuing mechanism for asynchronous processing in the queue you could store the DB Information for the worker process.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by running console commands? Which company database do you need to access? Are you an authentic user with regards to those company databases?

I haven't used yii2-app-advanced but in basic there is db config for web and for console separately.